# add array to an array without affecting the elements in array

Tags: python, arrays, list

Iam a beginer in python.Iam trying to add an array in a list but when i update that array and again append it to the list the previous appended array is also updated.Why is it happening?

```
list_of_sol=[]
a=[]
a.append(1)
list_of_sol.append(a)
a.append(2)
list_of_sol.append(a)
print list_of_sol
```

Output i was expecting was [[1],[1,2]] but output is [[1,2],[1,2]].

Answer (score 0):

You are appending references to the list object `a`.
This can be verified via `id()` of the two elements of the list.

```
>>> id(list_of_sol[1])
# 140477592091464
>>> id(list_of_sol[0])
# 140477592091464
```

So you end up appending two instances of a single object, rather than bare values. The expected behaviour can be realised using `list_of_sol.append(list(a))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output you've said you expected, do it like this:

```
list_of_sol=[]
a=[]
a.append(1)
list_of_sol.append(a[:])
a.append(2)
list_of_sol.append(a)
print list_of_sol
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be about copy and deepcopy:
list_of_sol.append(a)  puts a copy of a in list_of_sol, and this copy list_of_sol[0] refer to the same place with a, you can use id(list_of_sol[0]) == id(a) test it
You can check this :

```
from copy import deepcopy

list_of_sol=[]
a=[]
a.append(1)
list_of_sol.append(deepcopy(a[:])) #here changed
a.append(2)
list_of_sol.append(deepcopy(a)) #here changed
print list_of_sol
```